# How do a get the address of the pointer stored in a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

I'm trying to use the SDL2 library with c++ and as such, some of the functions need a double pointer to an SDL_Window or SDL_Renderer. I've malloc'ed some memory for an SDL_Window and gave that to a unique pointer like so:

```
window = unique_ptr<SDL_Window, decltype(free) *>
    reinterpret_cast<SDL_Window *>(malloc(sizeof(SDL_Window))),
    free};
```

and I used the following site as a guide for that: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820931/Using-std-unique-ptr-RAII-with-malloc-and-free

So now I need to get a pointer to the pointer stored inside the unique_ptr but I'm having trouble doing so.
I've tried things like:

```
&window.get()
// or
&&(*window)
// or
&window
// and even
&(&(*(window.get())))
```

All of these resulted in strange compiler errors like an l-value being required for the unary '&' operator which is entirely understandable for the first and last cases.

***Updates***
I now also use a raw SDL_Window * to get the address of and to give to unique_ptr. Some of my code snippets (out of context though):

```
SDL_Window *window_ptr;
unique_ptr<SDL_Window> window;

window = unique_ptr<SDL_Window, decltype(SDL_DestroyWindow)> (
    window_ptr,
    SDL_DestroyWindow);

SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(500, 500, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN, &window_ptr, &renderer_ptr);
```

But now, I'm running this compiler error:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h:272:18: error: no match for ‘operator=’ 
(operand types are ‘std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window>::deleter_type 
{aka std::default_delete<SDL_Window>}’ and ‘void (*)(void*)’)
get_deleter() = std::forward<_Ep>(__u.get_deleter());
```

Comment: Why are you allocating SDL_Window objects with malloc?

Comment: To Benjamin's question, I just realized that I don't do the memory allocation; SDL_CreateWindow does. I've modified my code to reflect that.

Comment: Yes, Hurkyl. I recognize that after taking a second to pause and think about the function haha. I still don't know why I'm getting this weird compiler error though, seemingly from inside of unique_ptr.h

Comment: But I'm not the one attempting to call that operator. It says unique_ptr.h is trying to.

Comment: Your update is basically a completely different question. One question per post, please.

Comment: In this example, you have the wrong type in your declaration of `window`. If you were going to do this a lot, I think I would `typedef unique_ptr<SDL_Window, decltype(SDL_DestroyWindow)> unique_window_ptr` or something like that. Or switch to `shared_ptr`, because a `shared_ptr` declaration doesn't need to record the type of the deleter.

Answer (score 12):

You cannot get the address of the pointer stored inside a `std::unique_ptr`. If you need to call C code that returns a pointer through a double pointer, you need to pass it the address of some other pointer and then separately have the `std::unique_ptr` take ownership of that pointer. If the `std::unique_ptr` allowed you to write directly to the stored pointer, it would have no way of releasing the resource it previously held.

Comment: All of which can be wrapped in a pretty class: http://ideone.com/uBlJzw

Comment: @Brian, what do you mean "You cannot get the address of the pointer stored inside a std::unique_ptr"? Isn't that what the [`.get()` method](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) is for?

Comment: @GabrielStaples no, `.get()` tells you the *value* of the pointer. The address of the pointer stored inside a `std::unique_ptr<T>` would have type `T**` - a pointer to the pointer itself.

Comment: Ah, right, I got it. You're not saying you can't obtain the address of the _object_ the `unique_ptr` points to (ie: the value of the pointer, which is what `.get()` provides), you're saying you can't get the address of the _pointer_ inside the `unique_ptr`, which stores the address of the object the `unique_ptr` points to. Because if  you _could_ obtain the address of the pointer itself, you might then be able to _manipulate or change it_, thereby violating the `unique_ptr`'s ownership of that pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Often, when you get tangled up in questions like these, it's a huge clue that *you're doing it wrong*.

For example, why do you need a `SDL_Window**`? Is it, for example, because you are calling `SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer`, a function that *creates* a window? That conflicts with the fact you've already created a window object and seemingly intend to use that.

Skimming briefly at the API, the intent seems to be that `SDL_Window` objects are **not** things that *you* create — they are things that the *library* creates.

e.g. what you really want to do is something lke

```
SDL_Window *window_;
SDL_Renderer *renderer_;
SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer (/* ... */, &window_, &renderer_);
unique_ptr<SDL_Window, decltype(&SDL_DestroyWindow)>
    window(window_, &SDL_DestroyWindow);
```

Comment: *"For example, why do you need a SDL_Window**..."* - The API demands it. *"what you really want to do is something like..."* - How do you get the authors of the library to change their code?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone visiting this question after 12/2020, C++20 now includes an overloaded stream insertion operator<< for unique pointers ( as well as the overloaded operator<=> and it **removed** the operator!= ). make sure you are specifying -std=c++20 in the command line, makefile, or using c++20 in your IDE.

Answer (score -3):

unique_ptr is one of the simpler stl classes - you can reimplement it and add a method to access the pointer inside.

The below code is an undefined behavior category ugly hack, but it actually works(tested in GCC using coliru online compiler with snippet below):

```
std::unique_ptr<myclass> uptr;
//Warning, undefined behavior!
myclass*& inside = *reinterpret_cast<myclass**>(&uptr);
```

Small test program to verify:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class myclass {
public:
    myclass() {
    }
    ~myclass() {
        std::cout << "It works!\n";
    }
};

int main()
{

    std::unique_ptr<myclass> uptr;
    //Warning, undefined behavior!
    myclass*& inside = *reinterpret_cast<myclass**>(&uptr);
    //Warning, undefined behavior!
    inside = new myclass();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I spot this in a code review, that developer and I are going to have a chat.

Comment: That developer realizes this code is dangerous.
He could protect his ass by writing #ifdef __GNUC__ and even versions around it to make this compile only on GCC where he's checked the standard headers.
Do you ever allow reinterpret_cast?

Comment: Can someone provide an overview of circumstances where this does / doesn't work?